# Add secure and httpOnly flags on Response cookies using NGINX

Tags: javascript, nginx, cookies

I'm new to `NGINX` and is in need of guidance.

Is it possible to add `secure` and `httponly` `flags` on `Response` cookies?

Below is the code that I added to the nginx config file:

`proxy_cookie_path / "/iwc; secure; HttpOnly";`

However, the `HTTP` and `secure` columns of the target response cookie on `chrome` are still **unchecked**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you already have the cookie set from backend. (`add-header Set-Cookie` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

The better way is to use proxy_cookie_flags from Nginx version 1.19.3

For all cookies use:

`proxy_cookie_flags ~ secure samesite=strict;`

For some of the cookies you can use (or regex):

`proxy_cookie_flags one httponly;`

Check more in documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link
https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-nginx/

need to add this module to your nginx and rebuild nginx.
How to add third party module to nginx, please follow below link
https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/

And add above proxy_cookie_path with set_cookie_flag HttpOnly Secure; in your nginx.conf file then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

proxy_cookie_path setting in article https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-nginx/ is misleading. it does NOT work for me.

actually, i just modify nginx.conf as below:

### add_header      Set-Cookie "user=$remote_user; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure"

then, it works.